# MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync() Image rotated 90 degree

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net-maui

When I Capture a Photo with the following code , I get the saved photo rotated 90 degree in **Android** and **iOS**

is there any solution for this issue? so I get the saved image orientation adjusted properly

```
FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
var picture = PlatformImage.FromStream(sourceStream);

string localFilePath = $"{FileSystem.CacheDirectory}/{photo.FileName}";
using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);
await picture.SaveAsync(localFileStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg, quality: 0.90f);
```

Comment: It's an known issue for the Essentials in the xamarin and maui, you can check [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514).

Answer (score 2):

The way I handled this was to implement my own `CapturePhotoAsync` for both iOS and Android so that the image is always being returned the right way up (using some of the code on this thread: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514). Then I can happily use `PlatformImage.FromStream` knowing that when I lose the exif data, the image is already the right way up anyway. It should also minimize changes once they fix this issue too.

I created the following interface:

```
public interface IImageService
{
    Task<FileResult> CapturePhotoAsync(MediaPickerOptions options = null);
}
```

Then under the `Platforms/Android` directory I created:

```
using Android.Graphics;
using AndroidX.ExifInterface.Media;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Path = System.IO.Path;
using Stream = System.IO.Stream;

namespace CaptureImageFix
{
    public enum ImageOrientation
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        Normal = 1,
        FlipHorizontal = 2,
        Rotate180 = 3,
        FlipVertical = 4,
        Transpose = 5,
        Rotate90 = 6,
        Transverse = 7,
        Rotate270 = 8
    }
    public partial class ImageService : IImageService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ImageService> _logger;

        public ImageService(ILogger<ImageService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<FileResult> CapturePhotoAsync(MediaPickerOptions options = null)
        {
            var fileResult = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync(options);
            if (fileResult == null)
                return null;
            await using var stream = await fileResult.OpenReadAsync();
            stream.Position = 0;
            var orientation = GetImageOrientation(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var originalBitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(stream);
            var matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case ImageOrientation.Normal:
                    break;
                case ImageOrientation.FlipHorizontal:
                    break;
                case ImageOrientation.Rotate180:
                    break;
                case ImageOrientation.FlipVertical:
                    matrix.PreRotate(180);
                    break;
                case ImageOrientation.Transpose:
                    matrix.PreRotate(90);
                    break;
                case ImageOrientation.Rotate90:
                    matrix.PreRotate(90);
                    break;
                case ImageOrientation.Transverse:
                    matrix.PreRotate(-90);
                    break;
                case ImageOrientation.Rotate270:
                    matrix.PreRotate(-90);
                    break;
            }
            var normalizedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(
                originalBitmap, 
                0, 
                0, 
                originalBitmap.Width, 
                originalBitmap.Height, 
                matrix, 
                true);
            using var outStream = new MemoryStream();
            await normalizedBitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, outStream);
            outStream.Position = 0;
            var jpegFilename = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpg");
            await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(jpegFilename, outStream.ToArray());
            return new FileResult(jpegFilename);
        }

        private ImageOrientation GetImageOrientation(Stream stream)
        {
            var exif = new ExifInterface(stream);
            var tag = exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagOrientation);
            var orientation = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag) ?
                ImageOrientation.Undefined :
                (ImageOrientation)Enum.Parse(typeof(ImageOrientation), tag);
            exif.Dispose();

            return orientation;
        }
    }
}
```

And under the `Platforms/iOS` directory I created (**note these are both partial classes and must be in the same namespace**):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform;
using MobileCoreServices;
using UIKit;

namespace CaptureImageFix
{
    public partial class ImageService : IImageService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ImageService> _logger;

        public ImageService(ILogger<ImageService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<FileResult> CapturePhotoAsync(MediaPickerOptions options = null)
        {
            return await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
                await InternalCapturePhotoAsync(options));
        }

        private async Task<FileResult> InternalCapturePhotoAsync(MediaPickerOptions options)
        {
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<FileResult>();
            if (await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>() == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController
                {
                    SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera,
                    MediaTypes = new string[] { UTType.Image }
                };

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(options?.Title))
                {
                    imagePicker.Title = options.Title;
                }

                var viewController = Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController();

                imagePicker.AllowsEditing = false;
                imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var jpegFilename = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpg");
                    var uiImage = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;
                    var normalizedImage = uiImage.NormalizeOrientation();
                    var normalizedData = normalizedImage.AsJPEG(new nfloat(1));
                    await viewController.DismissViewControllerAsync(true);
                    if (normalizedData.Save(jpegFilename, false, out var error))
                    {
                        taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(new FileResult(jpegFilename));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(new Exception($"Error saving the image: {error}"));
                    }
                    imagePicker?.Dispose();
                    imagePicker = null;
                };

                imagePicker.Canceled += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    await viewController.DismissViewControllerAsync(true);
                    taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(null);
                    imagePicker?.Dispose();
                    imagePicker = null;
                };

                await viewController.PresentViewControllerAsync(imagePicker, true);
            }
            else
            {
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(null);
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(new PermissionException("Camera permission not granted"));
            }

            return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `MauiProgram.cs` file add the following:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IImageService, ImageService>();
```

You can then inject the `IImageService` and use that to pick an image.

Each implementation overcomes specific issues with the native implementations of `MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync` provided by MAUI:

- **iOS**.  The MAUI implementation returns a PNG that has been stripped of the exif data and has not corrected the image.  The above implementation creates its own instance of `UIImagePickerController` and retrieves the image, corrects it, saves it as a jpeg, and then returns a `FileResult` pointing to that JPEG.
- **Android**.  The MAUI implementation returns a JPEG containing the exif data, however when a call to `PlatformImage.FromStream` is made it loses that data, so to nullify the effect of that, the implementation above wraps the call to `MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync` and then uses the exif data to create a new corrected version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Save the bytes of the source stream directly to the file stream.

Dont use an intermediate picture.

Comment: Is success only in ***Android*** when I avoid using the intermediate picture object , but not in ***iOS*** , but still I need the picture object to manipulate the photo (reduce the resolution & quality) because as you know we got very large photo file

Comment: Then look at the exif orientation info in the source and rotate the bitmap accordingly.

Comment: that what I was trying to do , but unfortunatly I could not find a way to do that with ***.NET MAUI***

Comment: also ***bitmap*** is part of ***Android.Graphics*** and that is not available in ***iOS***

Comment: That i dont know. Anyhow you have to look at the rotation information as the camera app can rotate the image as it wishes when only it tells in the -exif- info how.